# Concatenate static string with string that I bring from xml

Tags: html, xslt

I have `<h3>Reflow </h3>` and I want bring from xml `<xsl:value-of select="Machine/Id"/>`

How I can combine those two that the result will be something like `<h3>Reflow the value that I brought</h3>`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the standard XPath function [`concat()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-concat)**:

```
<h3><xsl:value-of select="concat('Reflow ', Machine/Id)"/></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or more simply:

```
<h3>Reflow: <xsl:value-of select="Machine/Id"/></h3>
```